# Creating Android library package including external (Native or Java) package

Tags: android, opencv, shared-libraries, static-libraries, native

I have developed an application for computer vision algorithms that uses Native `C++` library like `OpenCV` to capture camera frame and do image processing. My whole implementation resides in a native function which is called through an activity.

Let's say:

```
public native int MYMETHOD(int width, int height,int[] rgba);
```

I also load my library like this:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("MYNativeLIB");
}
```

Now my question is how can I deploy my application as a library package. Something deliverable that I can share it and the clients can import it to their project without installing any other libraries like `OpenCV`. Do I need to build a `.so` package?
I have read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html) article. But I do not know how can I link against `OpenCV` library as well.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the [static initialization for OpenCV4andorid](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization).  You then can add the Open CV lib into your /libs directory of your Library project without the need to install any third party app when using it.

Comment: Bundling OpenCV inside is not recommended because in future users may want to use different OpenCV version than yours. You should not provide OpenCV in jar but let users know that OpenCV library should be present. Look at various andorid or java libraries, they never contain their dependencies, you must deal with them or use maven/gradle

Comment: You are definitely right about using gradle/maven during development phase but the problem is that with openCV, you need to download the library on production which is not really user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created your project as a library? Maybe you could create a new project and port code with little effort. A very concise yet detailed explanation here:.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Answer (score 1):

> First you need to compile c/c++ files using android-ndk detailed
>   explanation here
>
> http://rathodpratik.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/build-cc-executables-for-android-using-ndk/
>
> Then you can successfully run your android project.